# Transforming XML to HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, xml, xslt

I am transforming XML into HTML using XSLT.

I have the following XML structure:

```
<Info><Description>
<p><strong><span style="font-family: Verdana; color: #f0b444;">Description<br />
<span class="BookingResultTxtBlue">description goes here.</span></span></strong></p>

<p><strong><span style="font-family: Verdana; color: #f0b444;"><span class="BookingResultTxtBlue">Test 1</span></span></strong></p>

<p><strong><span style="font-family: Verdana; color: #f0b444;"><span class="BookingResultTxtBlue">Test 2</span></span></strong></p>

<p><strong><span style="font-family: Verdana; color: #f0b444;"><span class="BookingResultTxtBlue">Test 3</span></span></strong></p>

</Description></Info>
```

My XSLT is as follows

```
<table>
 <tr>
      <td>
       <xsl:value-of  select='Info/Description'/>
     </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

After tansformation html is

```
<table>
 <tr> 
   <td>description goes here
       Test1
       Test2
       Test3
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

What i want here is, styles in original XML to be applied after transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Info/Description">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td Class="BookingResultTxtBlue">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Info">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first template copies all nodes, the second template does the transformation to your desired output, and the third template eliminates the `Info` node.

Comment: I am able to transform it correctly now. But i am facing a new problem while using template. Whenever there is &amp;nbsp; in description it is getting displayed as &nbsp;
Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Try to see this solution by Mads Hansen (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272212/xslt-1-0-cant-translate-apostrophe)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<xsl:value-of  select='Info/Description'/>
```

try:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="Info/Description/node()"/>
```