# XSLT 1.0 can’t translate apostrophe

Tags: xml, xslt, apostrophe

I have got the following content in my XML:

```
<MyElement> Cats&amp;apos; eyes </ MyElement >
```

When I use the following code in my XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:value-of select="MyElement" />
```

The output is

```
Cats&apos; eyes
```

But I want to get

```
Cats’ eyes
```

I tried

```
<xsl:value-of select='translate(MyElement, "&amp;apos; ", "&apos; ")'  />
```

But it didn’t work , the result was ca’ ey  with some **eliminated** characters!!!!

Any thought?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that it appears your content has been "double escaped". The entity for an apostrophe is `&apos;`, not `&amp;apos;`.

Your attempt to replace characters with **[`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate)** did not work, because it works differently than you are expecting. It is not a find/replace method. You specify a list of characters in the second argument and then the corresponding character to translate each one into in the third parameter. If there is no corresponding character in the list of characters in the third parameter then it will be removed.

You will need to use a [recursive template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520762/xslt-1-0-string-replace-function) to perform the character replacement.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="MyElement"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&amp;apos;'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="with" select='"&apos;"'/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="replace-string">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace"/>
        <xsl:param name="with"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text"
                        select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, with XSLT 2.0 you could just use the [**replace()**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) function:

```
<xsl:sequence select='replace(MyElement, "&amp;apos;", "&apos;")'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just add `disable-output-escaping="yes"`

```
<xsl:value-of select="MyElement" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Comment: aw, hastily done. I just copied and paste his example and I still get the text node of the input (not the output he is claiming). Sorry for that.

Comment: by the way, is the actual character an apostrophe or a right single quote?